# String split rows of dataframe based on pattern into new columns

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, strsplit

I have a data frame which looks like this

```
df

Country     Year  col3. col4. col5
USA2018      10    50    13   NA
UK 2018       4    12     6   NA
China       2018   15     4    1
Malta        NA    2018  25    8
```

I would like to split the strings of "Country" column by the pattern "2018" for the rows where 2018 is merged into the first column and shifted to the Year column for the rows where the Year is NA and have this output:

```
df

Country     Year  col3. col4. col5
USA         2018   10    50    13   
UK          2018   4    12     6   
China       2018   15    4    1
Malta       2018   25    8     NA
```

Any suggestion?

---

**Edit:** This data is result of PDF scraping.[Link to PDF](https://nvbdcp.gov.in/WriteReadData/l892s/77993592821580734272.pdf), and the code below:

```
# install.packages("pdftools") 
# install.packages("readr") 
library(pdftools) 
library(readr) 


epi <- pdf_text("malaria_epi.pdf") 
epi_df <- epi %>% 
  read_lines() %>% 
  grep('^\\s{2}\\w', ., value = TRUE) %>% 
  paste(collapse = '\n') %>% read_fwf(fwf_empty(.))
```

Comment: I think data import gone wrong, how does the raw file look like?

Comment: it is scraped from pdf

Comment: If you can, could you provide the PDF, and codes used for scraping? If not this can be done with regex. But I was hoping we could fix the import step rather than dealing with problem created by import. (XY problem)

Comment: I edited your post with more details, in future, please use "edit".

Comment: See this [related post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/need-to-extract-tables-from-a-pdf-using-r/17144/4?u=zx8754) using tabulizer:

Comment: yeah I am ckecking that R package right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. It was a bit tricky, but I think it cover your case.
This solution could be problematic if you have NA in the middle of a row, but I didn't manage to find a better way yet.

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, 
                 text="
Country     Year  col3. col4. col5
USA2018      10    50    13   NA
UK2018       4    12     6   NA
China       2018   15     4    1
Malta        NA    2018  25    8")

tmpN <- names(df) # save the colnames
df = cbind(df[,1],df) # duplicate the first column
df[,c(1,2)] <- lapply(df[,c(1,2)], as.character)

df[,1] = sub('[[:digit:]]+','',df[,1]) # remove date in first column
df[,2] = sub('[[:alpha:]]+','',df[,2]) # remove city in second column
df[df==''] <- NA # replace empty cells with NA

# push all NA to the right side
df2 = as.data.frame(t(apply(df,1, function(x) { return(c(x[!is.na(x)],x[is.na(x)]) )} )))
df2 <- df2[,!(colSums(is.na(df2))==nrow(df2))] # remove column full of NA

colnames(df2) <- tmpN # replace colnames
```